# how to filter many-to-many fields in django models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models: `User` , `Tag` and `Recipe`.
`User` model is so basic and it's not important.
Here is the `Tag` model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , on_delete=CASCADE)
```

And here is the `Recipe` model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',)
```

I made endpoint for all of these models but there is one problem!
When I try to create a `Recipe` object, all of `Tag` objects will be listed, But I want to list just the logged in user tags.

Here is my `Tag` serializer:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Tag
        fields = ('id' , 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id' : {
                'read_only' : True,
            }
        }
```

And here is my `Tag` viewset:

```
class TagsView(viewsets.GenericViewSet,mixins.CreateModelMixin,mixins.ListModelMixin):

    queryset = models.Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TagSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

How can I filter tags, so that all listed tag objects belong to the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

A `queryset` is created only once, that is when you start the server. So the queryset attribute is evaluated when the process starts that is when your page renders which causes the `class TagsView` view to execute.

A `get_queryset` method is called upon every request, which can be particularly useful if you want to adjust the query dynamically, which I think you are trying to do here.
So the `get_queryset` is a method that is supposed to be used in place of `queryset` variable as an alternative to it, providing more flexibility.

You really don't need both of them together, which might be causing your problem.
You can just do it this way.

```
class TagsView(RecipeAttrsView):

    serializer_class = serializers.TagSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Tags.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```